# Html form: easiest way to define value of control based on other controls on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to send the age instead of year born from the form to the server when the submit button is clicked. What is the easiest way to achieve it?

```
<form action="process.php">
    <input type="text" name="yearBorn">
    <input type="hidden" name="Age">
    <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: Calculate it on the server side.

Comment: Plus, just the year is very inaccurate.

Comment: Most people know how old they are. Since you're discarding the year, why not ask for the age directly?

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer. This code is a sample for a complex problem that I have.
Specifically, I'm wondering if there are any overrides for when the browser accesses the value of the "Age" field. I'm not a noob :(

Comment: Well, what have you got so far?

Comment: I could just write my own onSubmit() function but I don't want to interfere with that. I want to know if there's a better way.

Comment: You could capture the blur event of the yearBorn input?

Comment: Why not grab the submit event?

Comment: _I'm wondering if there are any overrides for when the browser accesses the value of the "Age" field._ Nothing built in that I'm aware of. You have to write some kind of handler.

Comment: @Jeffman because my actual form is quite a big one and I will have to do everything manually if I decide to capture the submit event. I want something more low level.  

Will blur event work if the value of the field "yearBorn" is itself assigned programmatically on the page?

Comment: @shishirgarg, are you using jQuery?  If you are, you can change the value and then call blur, e.g., `$('#year').val('2012').blur()`

Comment: That means you can write a blur handler that works on its own and can be called programmatically as well. (In case that wasn't clear.)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I am using jquery. That's a good suggestion. I think I will end up using that since it looks like there is no way to simply override a "getter" for "Age"

Answer (score 2):

Here are your options, in my personal preference order.

#### Server

Handle this on the server.  I understand you don't like that solution, but what if the use has JavaScript disabled?  The only cases where this makes sense, is when you don't control the server (e.g. submitting to some other site's page).

It's also a security risk.  I could easily send a fake POST saying that my year of birth is 2042 and I'm 39,239 years old, which for some reason could cause your app to crash, especially if you try to store it in a 16 bit signed integer.

#### MVC, MVVM, etc.

Use some solution that lets you define links between data and your view.  Here's a KnockoutJS example, while some people prefer Backbone or AngularJS.

```
<input type="text" name="yearBorn" data-bind="value: yearBorn">
<input type="hidden" name="Age" data-bind="value: 2013 - parseInt(yearBorn())">
```

#### Handle it in a change handler (more reliable than `blur`).

```
$('input[name=yearBorn]').change(function(){
    $('input[name=Age]').val(2013 - parseInt($(this).val()));
});
```

It can also be triggered.

```
$('input[name=yearBorn]').val('1993').change(); // sets Age to 20
```

#### Ask Them Their Age

Might be worth considering, but it's your app.

Answer (score 1):

"*A Javascript/[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) solution that isn't based on capturing events from `yearBorn`*"? This is the only solution I could come up with:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    // Prevents the form from being submitted
    e.preventDefault();

    // Find outs the age
    var age = new Date().getFullYear() - $('input[name="yearBorn"]').val();

    // Submits the form through AJAX, so in server-side you can get the age
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: {'age': age},
        success: function (data) {
            // If successful, do your stuff here
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would server side calculation as suggested resolve the problem/do you need a definitive JavaScript solution?

```
$age = $date("Y") - $_POST[yearBorn];
```

Would do the trick.

Comment: I need a javascript/jquery solution that isn't based on capturing events from "yearBorn"

Comment: @shishirgarg - How can you calculate the age without using the `yearBorn`?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I want to access the value of `yearBorn` but not its events.

Comment: @shishirgarg - What do you mean "its event"?

Comment: events exposed by input element like onChange